# Определение принадлежности точки выделенной области

Tags: pascalabc.net

Вроде все правильно, но ошибка все равно выходит. Заранее спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код :

```
uses crt;
var
    Xa,Xb,Xc,Ya,Yb,Yc,x,y:integer;
    ab,bc,ac,s1,s2,p1,p2,ax,xc:real;
begin
    read(Xa,Xb,Xc,Ya,Yb,Yc,x,y);

    if (x<=xc) and (y>=0) and (x>=xa) and (y<=yb) then
    begin
        ab:=sqrt(sqr(xb-xa)+sqr(yb-ya));
        bc:=sqrt(sqr(xc-xb)+sqr(yc-yb));
        ac:=sqrt(sqr(xc-xa)+sqr(yc-ya));
        p1:=(ab+bc+ac)/2;
        s1:=sqrt(p1*(p1-ab)*(p1-bc)*(p1-ac));
        ax:=sqrt(sqr(xb-xa)+sqr(yb-ya));
        xc:=sqrt(sqr(xb-xa)+sqr(yb-ya));
        p2:=(ax+xc+ac)/2;
        s2:=sqrt(p2*(p2-ax)*(p2-xc)*(p2-ac));
    end
    else
    if s1<=s2 then
        write('Точка принадлежит выделенной области')
    else
        write('Точка не принадлежит выделенной области');

    else write('Точка не принадлежит выделенной области');
end.
```

Comment: "но ошибка все равно выходит" - это на каком языке?  Вы понимаете, что если выполнение не заходит в `if`, то `s1` и `s2` остаются невычисленными, а если заходит, то `else if` выполнятся не будет?

Answer (score 1):

Зачем так много сложностей?
В приведённой картинке область задана явно.
Формулу можно сократить:

```
begin
  var x, y : Real;
  ReadLn(x, y);
  WriteLn('Точка ', Not((abs(x) <= 4) and (y >= 0) and (y <= 4) and (y + abs(x) <= 4)) ? 'не ' : '' , 'принадлежит выделенной области.');
end.
```